# PHP Change Page width on Second Page (mPDF)

Tags: php, mpdf

can anyone tell me on how could I change the page size on the second (2nd) page using `mpdf`. My page size is A4 (by `mpdf` default).

I want to dynamically changed the width of second page of my report since it's dynamic content of table (e.g. number of columns is undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know where your first page ends, you can use the AddPage() function to change the formatting of the next page.

```
 $mpdf=new mPDF();
 $mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Introduction');
 $mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',50,50,50,50,10,10);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Book text');
 $mpdf->AddPage('P','','','','',50,50,50,50,10,10);
```